# Use different constructors at runtime

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have got 2 constructors in my class:

```
Class()
Class(const std::string &fileName)
```

I don't want my fileName to be set elsewhere the constructor.
But the constructor call depends at runtime:

```
int main(int ac, char**av)
{
  if (ac > 1)
    Class test(av[1])
  else
    Class test;
  return (0);
}
```

This notation does not compile cause "Class was not defined in the scope"

The other solution is to use a Class pointer:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  Class  *test;

  if (ac > 1)
    test = new Class(av[1]);
  else
    test = new Class();
  /* Do stuff ...*/
  delete test;
  return (0);
}
```

But I prefer not to use new.
Is there an other way ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is passing an empty string when you want default initialization not an option?

Comment: What's so wrong with using the second solution. If you store it in a `std::shared_ptr ` you'll be ok

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Your first code sample [works fine](http://ideone.com/5Sm660) for me. How do you define your class?

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, that works, but you can then not use `test` after the `if` statement, because you actually have two distinct variables, both named `test`, each of which has a scope limited to one branch of the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Jarod42's answer is fine, you can also do that without a function:

```
Class test = (ac > 1) ? Class(av[1]) : Class();
```

Which is better is matter of taste of course. For complex cases, function is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like:

```
Class make_class(int ac, char**av)
{
    if (ac > 1) {
        return Class(av[1]);
    } else {
        return Class();
    }
}


int main(int ac, char**av)
{
    Class test = make_class(ac, av);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the class copyable and/or movable in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If Jarod's answer is not an option (because you can't make the class copyable and you're not using C++11), here are some other options:

- Allocate with `new` and store in a `boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`. (`shared_ptr` is overkill.)
- Use a `boost::optional` and emplace into that.